# $||Ax||^2$ = $(Ax)^T(Ax)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $||Ax||^2$ = $(Ax)^T(Ax)$, but I am curious as to exactly why the squared norm of Ax has this sort of quadratic relationship. IS there a theorem or condition that establishes this?

Especially considering that the matrix norm of A is the max of the column  vectors.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the matrix norm of A". You can define different norms for a matrix. Consider a vector $y=Ax$.  The l2-norm of $y$ is simply $y^Ty$. Apply this definition to get the result you have.

Comment: $Ax$ is simply a vector, so you're taking a vector norm, not a matrix norm.

Comment: @arctic tern I agree. I was just trying out to point to OP that there are different matrix norms, it is a choice of how it is induced.

Comment: @felasfa Sorry, didn't fully read your comment, deleted mine.

Comment: @arctic tern no problem. I was not sure what OP meant in his last line so wanted to clarify that. You gave a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

The dot $u\cdot v$ for column vectors $u,v$ is equal to $u^Tv$. Lookie:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix}=[u_1 v_1+u_2 v_2+\cdots+u_n v_n]. $$

(Of course we must think of $1\times 1$ matrices as scalars for this interpretation to make sense.)

In particular, this means $\|u\|^2=u\cdot u=u^Tu$.

Applying with $u=Ax$ gives $\|Ax\|^2=(Ax)^T(Ax)$.

Comment: How to show this holds for frobenius norm as well?

Comment: @JohnD How to show what holds for the Frobenius norm?

Comment: $$||AB|| _F^2=(AB)^T(AB)$$

Comment: @JohnD That's clearly not true. The left side of that is a scalar, the right side is a matrix. Put a trace on the right side and then it's true *by definition*: $\|X\|_F^2:={\rm tr}(X^TX)$.

Comment: Can I say this is $L_2$ norm?